# Xamarin Forms Multi-App - MacOS project not showing Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, multiplatform

**Edit:  Added link to project I created:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A4XGKdxeC22_wqtNEtenLxYbgCp3I_dA/view?usp=sharing

I have a very basic multi-platform application created I Visual Studio 2019 (Windows 10) with 4 projects:
Source Project
Android
iOS
UWP

I added the MacOS project following these instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/mac

The application compiles but loads a blank form and does not show any of the Xamarin forms as per the UWP, iOS and Android apps.

I next created an empty Multi-Platform application natively on a Mac - added the MacOS as per the above instructions and get the same outcome, a blank form loading.

The code I am using in the Mac project is the link above.

```
// AppDelelegate.cs
using AppKit;
using Foundation;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS;
using pbTrader;

namespace pbTrader.MacOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        NSWindow window;
        public AppDelegate()
        {
            var style = NSWindowStyle.Closable | NSWindowStyle.Resizable | NSWindowStyle.Titled;

            var rect = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(200, 1000, 1024, 768);
            window = new NSWindow(rect, style, NSBackingStore.Buffered, false);
            window.Title = "Xamarin.Forms on Mac!"; // choose your own Title here
            window.TitleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
        }

        public override NSWindow MainWindow
        {
            get { return window; }
        }

        public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
        {
            Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            base.DidFinishLaunching(notification);
        }

        public override void WillTerminate(NSNotification notification)
        {
            // Insert code here to tear down your application
        }
    }
}


// Main.cs
using AppKit;

namespace pbTrader.MacOS
{
    static class MainClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NSApplication.Init();
            NSApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate = new AppDelegate(); // add this line
            NSApplication.Main(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are any exceptions thrown when loading the mac app? Did you make sure that the Main.storyboard is not the initial view controller? Is your forms app class initialising? Is your view initialising? Did you put the init code in DidFinishLaunching?

Comment: @Axemasta  I just added the code I am using.  Yes, main.storyboard is not the initial controller (unticked) and I removed this from the project.    LoadApplication(new App()) is initialising and I can step into it ok in the parent project.

Comment: Also I have added Xamarin.Forms and Essentials packages via nuget and reference the parent project pbTrader.  I also renamed the Assembly name because it conflicts with UWP assembly name.

Comment: Are all the xamarin.forms versions the same? Does it work when you create a file > new project? I created a brand new project and Mac was showing my forms main page view

Comment: Yes all xmarin.forms are the same.  Did you create your project on a Mac or PC?  I have access to both devices in front of me?  On the Mac, I created a new Multi-Platform solutions (it only gave IOS, Android and the parent). So I added the MacOs.  On Windows the default Multi-Platform was UWP, iOS and Android (and the parent) so I opened it on the Mac and added the Mac Cocoa App as per the Microsoft instructions.

Comment: I've done it with projects created on both, in this instance I created it all from macOS. File > New Solution > Multiplatform > Blank Forms App (Run once on iOS to check). Then all the steps in the guide & it worked. What forms versions are you using? are you on the latest visual studio & macOS?

Comment: I've seen forms mac apps display nothing before in the cases where theyre referencing unimplemented controls (such as `CollectionView`), but if its happening in new projects then there could be another issue. Also is your xcode up to date?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I re-built a new test app from scratch (as per your comments above) using my Mac instead of a PC and Mac App works now.. so next is to add the UWP project via Windows 10 and try again!

Comment: @Belliez Seems that you have solved your problem now?

Comment: @Cherry Bu, no sadly. To replicate, on Windows 10 using VS2019 I created a default Xamarin project using the Fly-out template for iOS, Android, UWP.  Then I open up the solution on the Mac and create the MacOS project exactly following the instructions from the Microsoft page linked here.  When I run the MacOS project a blank page is opened.  Running the UWP (on Windows 10), iOS or Android (both Mac or PC) shows correctly.  I have edited my question and added a link to the project source code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A4XGKdxeC22_wqtNEtenLxYbgCp3I_dA/view?usp=sharing